# No Overload for Method "Contains"

Tags: c#, overloading

So I have a

```
if (toolStripTextBox1.Text.Contains("text1", "text2", "text3", ... "text139"
```

and then I started adding 139 items until I realized it didn't work

how would I overload the Contains method? Or just bypass the limit..

Comment: Why would you overload the `Contains` method when you could just put all these strings in an array and use LINQ or a loop?

Comment: a regex might be better too.

Comment: You're not writing a "swear-word" blocker or "invalid password" blocker, are you?

Comment: It's a bit strange that you have 139 static strings, are you sure that you don't want to put those strings into a separate file (or resource) to make it more manageable?

Comment: @dreamlax they are roughly 3-6 characters each and im going to have about 1000 when im done, and no it is not a swear-word blocker.

Comment: write your own extension method...maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LINQ:

```
var items = new[]{"text1", "text2", "text3", ... "text139"};

if (items.Any(item => toolStripTextBox1.Text.Contains(item)) ...
```

Comment: You should note that this will only work with LinqToObjects.

Comment: This actually worked :P Thanks, I had no idea I could do something like this, after all I am completely new to c# and I only know basic and some specific intermediate stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's simply an `AND` operation. What you really want to achieve is to know whether a text simultaneously contains `text1` AND `text2` AND `text3` and so forth. So simply you want `str.Contains("text1") && str.Contains("text2")`.

But pretty much it seems like you are doing some code smell. However, we are not aware of the full scenario. It will be better to add all the parts in a collection, loop through it and check if the string contains each of the values.

If you want to check if your text box contains at least one word, you can stop on the first occurrence:

```
string[] words = { "text1", "text2", "text3" };
foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (toolStripTextBox1.Text.Contains(word)) break;
}
```

If you want to check if your text box contains all the words, you need to stop on the first word which is not contained and flag that something's wrong:

```
string[] words = { "text1", "text2", "text3" };
bool allFound = true;

foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (!toolStripTextBox1.Text.Contains(word))
    {
        allFound = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (allFound) { // }
```

This is exactly how `Any()` and `All()` extension methods from `System.Linq` work. So you can use them instead (less code)

```
string[] words = { "text1", "text2", "text3" };
if (words.All(w => toolStripTextBox1.Text.Contains(w))
{
    // do smth if all words are contained
}
```

Or

```
string[] words = { "text1", "text2", "text3" };
if (words.Any(w => toolStripTextBox1.Text.Contains(w))
{
    // do smth if at least one word is contained
}
```

Comment: I am completely aware with || and && but writing str.Contains 1000+ times is going to be a pain, even copying and pasting.

Comment: As stated in the answer you can loop at each word and write only once `if contains` or `if not contains` (depending on what you want to achieve). You can abstract that using `Any()` or `All()` extension methods for IEnumerable types from `System.Linq`

Comment: @JakeF. I have added some examples

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own extension method of it some thing like:

```
public enum Operation
{
     And,
     Or
}

public static bool Contains(this string text,Operation operation,params string[] args) 
 {
    switch(operation)
    {
        case Operation.And:
            return args.All(item => text.Contains(item));
        case Operation.Or:
            return args.Any(item => text.Contains(item));
        default:
            return false;
    }
 }
```

and use it like

```
if(toolStripTextBox1.Text.Contains(Operation.And,"text1", "text2", "text3"))
```

OR

```
if(toolStripTextBox1.Text.Contains(Operation.Or,"text1", "text2", "text3"))
```